# How to use self in python

Tags: python

I'm new to programming and I want someone to explain using 'self' in python in the following context.

```
class Box:
    def __init__(self):
        self.length = 1.0
        self.width = 1.0
        self.height = 1.0    

    def set_dimensions(self, newL, newW, newH):
        self.length = newL
        self.width = newW
        self.height = newH          

    def volume(self):
        return (self.length * self.width * self.height)

box = Box:
box.set_dimensions(2.0,3.0,4.0)
print(box.volume())
```

This code causes an exception:

```
Error: box.set_dimensions(2.0,3.0,4.0) needs exactly 4 arguments, 3 given
```

Can someone explain how to use 'self' when calling methods please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parenthesis to create an instance of your class

```
box = Box()                       # Use parenthesis here not :
box.set_dimensions(2.0,3.0,4.0)   # Now no error
print(box.volume())               # Prints 24.0
```

Answer (score 2):

If you write `box = Box`, you make `box` a variable referring to a class `Box`. It's very rare that you would need a variable to refer to a class. When calling method of a class, you need to supply an instance of that class as the first argument, but you haven't created any such instance.

Instead, write `box = Box()` - that would create and instance of the class `Box`. And then the remainder of the code would be valid. When calling a class method on a class instance, the instance is passed as an additional first argument, the one that is named `self` in the method definition.

Answer (score 0):

To add something to the answer, you can try to understand `self` in class function variables as something that when it is encoutnered python internally converts the objects method into calling it from the class, so when you are calling

```
SomeBoxObject.setDimensions(someLen, otherLen, evenOtherLen)
```

Python turns this into

```
Box.setDimensions(SomeBoxObject, someLen, otherLen, evenOtherLen)
```